# onComponentSave (SaveEventArgs)

Tags: 2013, event-system

I'm setting up some basic functions for a Tridion 2013 SP1 EventSystem.
The idea is simple, set the date on the metadata of a component when the metadata field is left empty. Now it seems that the event system thinks it's a new component and returns the following error.

```
An exception of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ItemDoesNotExistException' occurred in Tridion.ContentManager.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The item tcm:3-4437-16-v0 does not exist.
```

The component uri of the component updating is: tcm:3-4437-16 so for some reason the eventsystem thinks it's a new component (-v0).

so here is my code:

**EventSubscription**

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(ContentEvents.OnComponentSave, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

**The Class Function**

```
public static void OnComponentSave(Component component, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Log.Info(component, "OnComponentSave " + component.MetadataSchema.Title);

        if (component.Metadata!=null)
        {
            var metadata = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);
            var standardMeta = metadata.GetEmbeddedField("embed_standard_meta");

            Log.Info(component, "OnComponentSave There is a metadata schema ");

            if (standardMeta != null)
            {
                Log.Info(component, "OnComponentSave There is metadata");

                if (standardMeta.GetDateValue("date_creation") == null || ((DateField)standardMeta["date_creation"]).Value == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    ((DateField)standardMeta["date_creation"]).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    component.Metadata = metadata.ToXml();
                    Log.Info(component, "OnComponentSave " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope any one can point me in the right direction, it's kinda frustrating.

Comment: user978511 has it right - you want this to happen _before_ the item is saved. Just wanted to point out that -v0 means "current latest version", not "new item".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only obvious problem is that you should subscribe to `EventPhases.Initiated` instead of `EventPhases.TransactionCommitted`. Other than that it looks fine, unless you are calling `component.Save` somewhere down the line.

Comment: Thanks, the EventPahase was indeed the wrong one. It tryed to add metadata after the component was saved.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the event in transaction committed phase. But editable version of the component is not available during this phase. Subscribe to the event during Initiated phase.